# Same jquery functions, different settings

Tags: jquery

I have two same jquery functions but with the different settings.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-link').bigSlide({
        'menu': ('#slide'),
        'side': 'right',
        'menuWidth': '28.585%'
    });
    $('.menu-link-wide').bigSlide({
        'menu': ('#slide'),
        'side': 'right',
        'menuWidth': '90%'
    });
});
```

I guess this can be written nicer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the settings.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var defaults = {
        menu: '#slide',
        side: 'right'
    };
    $('.menu-link').bigSlide($.extend({}, defaults, {
        menuWidth: '28.585%'
    }));
    $('.menu-link-wide').bigSlide($.extend({}, defaults, {
        menuWidth: '90%'
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could extend your common parameter using `$.extend`:

```
var param = { menu: '#slide', side: 'right' };

$('.menu-link').bigSlide($.extend({'menuWidth': '28.585%'}, param));

$('.menu-link-wide').bigSlide($.extend({menuWidth: '90%'}, param));
```